# ModelAndView object.addAttribute() equivalent to request.setAttribute

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

Just a clarification. Is ModelAndView object.addAttribute() equivalent to request.setAttribute. I went through a Spring MVC example
the author added an attribute with ModelAndView object.addAttribute(), then in the jsp
retrieved it with request.getAttribute().

I tried the same example, it worked for me. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ModelAndView#addObject(key,value)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#addObject%28java.lang.String,java.lang.Object%29) puts the attribute in the `request` scope.